# MySQL queries not running on command line

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, ubuntu-14.04

I am using MySQL through command line in ubuntu. After the 'use database_name', only 'desc table_name' is working. I am not able to run any of select, update, insert, alter table queries. When I hit the query with ';' at the end, I just see blank result.

mysql> SELECT * FROM WEB_POLICY;

and the console stops. No error displayed. Anybody has idea, what might be wrong ? Connection is not a problem, as its local host. I was able to run queries successfully till an hour back.

Comment: So the MSQL Console just stops and switches you back to the terminal? Have you tried restarting Mysql and seeing if it works?

Comment: hi...restarting the computer helped. MySQL console just stopped after hitting the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not console stops, it's query executing. Probaly, the table is big, and `SELECT *` - the most inefficent possible query - may take a lot of time to execute. Try something easier to test everything works, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM WEB_POLICY LIMIT 10
```

for example (if it has an `id` column, of course).

Edit: if it is not big table, then the most possible issue is uncommited transaction in another console or application (if engine is InnoDB), or LOCK'ed table (if engine is MyISAM). 
For MyISAM you release lock by `UNLOCK TABLES WEB_POLICY`. For InnoDB it may be a bit harder:
1. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` for displaying all active connections
2. `KILL` ones with "query" status.

Or just simply restart server (fine for localhost) for forced rollback open transactions and release locks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried 'select * from WEB_POLICY limit 1', even that is not working. I am not able to figure out what might be the issue as I was able to hit the queries before and data didn't change.

Comment: That's intresting. Tables uses InnoDB as engine? If so, check  `show engine innodb status;` command output for errors.

Comment: It could also be active transaction (if InnoDB) in another console (or started by another application), or LOCK'ed table (if MyISAM).

Comment: Hi...I restarted my computer today. Now the MySQL console seems fine. Thanks.